# MS Access MAX and MIN functions not returning correct result

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an automated report in MS access, and this query selects the Lowest Hours, Highest Hours, Average Hours, and Total Hours, for each person, from all the records in a given date range.

```
SELECT tbl.Consultant, round(avg(tbl.HoursSpent),0) as Average, Min(tbl.HoursSpent) as Lowest, Max(tbl.HoursSpent) as Highest, Sum(tbl.HoursSpent) as Total
FROM tbl
WHERE 
(tbl.Canceled = false)
AND (
(tbl.DateIn >= [Forms]![Reports]![ReportStartDate])
AND 
(tbl.DateIn <= [Forms]![Reports]![ReportEndDate])
)
GROUP BY tbl.Consultant
```

Rather than getting the expected result: MIN producing the lowest number of hours in any record, and MAX producing highest hours; the query produces MINs that are higher than the MAXs in some cases.

Example:
[image: Incorrect Query Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, after I post on SO, I think of a way to change the query.

For future MS Access users who encounter this problem:

The MAX and MIN functions do not automatically convert values into integers!
Use **Val()** make sure every value is converted into an integer:

`MAX(Val(NumberValue))` or `MIN(Val(NumberValue))`

This is not an issue with the SUM() and AVG() functions, because they can only process integers, and so automatically do a conversion. MIN() and MAX() can be used for Dates and other field types, so an explicit conversion is necessary.

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the data type of `tbl.HoursSpent` ?

Comment: Text, of course! Need to learn to check these things when querying databases set up by other people.

Comment: Ouch. :) Now that you wrote it, the left alignment in the datasheet gives it away.